# Get flight's logo images in a flight list using flight offer price API

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, amadeus

I want to show flight's logo images in a flight list using flight offer price API:

```
https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference.
```

I search for flights using origin and destination, one way or round trip, etc. But the flight logo image is not available in the result. Is there a way I can get the flight logo image using the "flight-offers-search" API?

I have used bellow API URL to get flight offer price
This is my request URL

```
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=MAN&destinationLocationCode=LAX&departureDate=2021-07-29&adults=1&travelClass=ECONOMY¤cyCode=USD&max=100
```

This is my API response. there is no flight logo image available in the response.

```
 stdClass Object
    (
        [meta] => stdClass Object
            (
                [count] => 93
                [links] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [self] => https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=MAN&destinationLocationCode=LAX&departureDate=2021-07-29&adults=1&travelClass=ECONOMY¤cyCode=USD&max=100
                    )
    
            )
    
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [type] => flight-offer
                        [id] => 1
                        [source] => GDS
                        [instantTicketingRequired] => 
                        [nonHomogeneous] => 
                        [oneWay] => 
                        [lastTicketingDate] => 2021-07-29
                        [numberOfBookableSeats] => 4
                        [itineraries] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [duration] => PT29H42M
                                        [segments] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [departure] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [iataCode] => MAN
                                                                [terminal] => 1
                                                                [at] => 2021-07-29T10:40:00
                                                            )
    
                                                        [arrival] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [iataCode] => LIS
                                                                [terminal] => 1
                                                                [at] => 2021-07-29T13:30:00
                                                            )
    
                                                        [carrierCode] => TP
                                                        [number] => 1317
                                                        [aircraft] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [code] => 32N
                                                            )
    
                                                        [operating] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [carrierCode] => TP
                                                            )
    
                                                        [duration] => PT2H50M
                                                        [id] => 152
                                                        [numberOfStops] => 0
                                                        [blacklistedInEU] => 
                                                    )
    
                                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [departure] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [iataCode] => LIS
                                                                [terminal] => 1
                                                                [at] => 2021-07-29T18:30:00
                                                            )
    
                                                        [arrival] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [iataCode] => EWR
                                                                [terminal] => B
                                                                [at] => 2021-07-29T21:30:00
                                                            )
    
                                                        [carrierCode] => TP
                                                        [number] => 207
                                                        [aircraft] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [code] => 32Q
                                                            )
    
                                                        [operating] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [carrierCode] => TP
                                                            )
    
                                                        [duration] => PT8H
                                                        [id] => 153
                                                        [numberOfStops] => 0
                                                        [blacklistedInEU] => 
                                                    )
    
                                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [departure] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [iataCode] => JFK
                                                                [terminal] => 5
                                                                [at] => 2021-07-30T05:30:00
                                                            )
    
                                                        [arrival] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [iataCode] => LAX
                                                                [terminal] => 3
                                                                [at] => 2021-07-30T08:22:00
                                                            )
    
                                                        [carrierCode] => TP
                                                        [number] => 4325
                                                        [aircraft] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [code] => 32S
                                                            )
    
                                                        [operating] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [carrierCode] => B6
                                                            )
    
                                                        [duration] => PT5H52M
                                                        [id] => 154
                                                        [numberOfStops] => 0
                                                        [blacklistedInEU] => 
                                                    )
    
                                            )
    
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [price] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [currency] => USD
                                [total] => 845.85
                                [base] => 581.00
                                [fees] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [amount] => 0.00
                                                [type] => SUPPLIER
                                            )
    
                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [amount] => 0.00
                                                [type] => TICKETING
                                            )
    
                                    )
    
                                [grandTotal] => 845.85
                            )
    
                        [pricingOptions] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [fareType] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => PUBLISHED
                                    )
    
                                [includedCheckedBagsOnly] => 1
                            )
    
                        [validatingAirlineCodes] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => TP
                            )
    
                        [travelerPricings] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [travelerId] => 1
                                        [fareOption] => STANDARD
                                        [travelerType] => ADULT
                                        [price] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [currency] => USD
                                                [total] => 845.85
                                                [base] => 581.00
                                            )
    
                                        [fareDetailsBySegment] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [segmentId] => 152
                                                        [cabin] => ECONOMY
                                                        [fareBasis] => LUKBSI0D
                                                        [class] => L
                                                        [includedCheckedBags] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [quantity] => 1
                                                            )
    
                                                    )
    
                                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [segmentId] => 153
                                                        [cabin] => ECONOMY
                                                        [fareBasis] => LUKBSI0D
                                                        [class] => L
                                                        [includedCheckedBags] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [quantity] => 1
                                                            )
    
                                                    )
    
                                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [segmentId] => 154
                                                        [cabin] => ECONOMY
                                                        [fareBasis] => LUKBSI0D
                                                        [brandedFare] => BASIC
                                                        [class] => L
                                                        [includedCheckedBags] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [quantity] => 1
                                                            )
    
                                                    )
    
                                            )
    
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                    )
```

Or anyone know if there are any other api's that I can use to get the logos?
Please help to get flight logo using Amadeus API
I have used Amadeus test API
Thank you

Comment: Regarding Amadeus APIs, currently there is no available API that returns logos.